# How to deal with low quality questions that are totally valid?

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts

As I was browsing Stack Overflow I stumbled upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36093873/3502980). While the question seems perfectly valid, it doesn't show any effort from the OP. The straightforward answer of moving a part of the code outside of a loop in order to make it not repeat tells me that the asker has *little to no knowledge* of programming. I understand this is not an elitist community, and I'm fine with that, still the question seems below the standards to me, what can I do about it?

Comment: You're right that it looks like a valid, on-topic question to me. You can always downvote the question for lack of research if you feel it merits it. (If I'd stumbled upon that naturally, _I_ certainly would downvote for that.) Otherwise, if it's on-topic there's really nothing you can do about it.

Comment: By the time I did that it had already been voted up once, which makes me think he's rep-trading (or whatever the term is called), as nobody in their right mind would upvote it.

Comment: *"as nobody in their right mind would upvote it"* you'd be surprised. Downvote it even if it feels like a losing battle.

Comment: Downvote, downvote, downvote.  If you're feeling extra helpful, let the OP know what they can do to improve their question; or if you're really feeling helpful, edit it for them to get it upvotes.

Comment: I guess we are doomed to have to provide Google hits for people that don't know how to spell "retrieve".  Done.  Don't fix it please, we don't need the next one.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker There is nothing to be done to improve the question (in this case).

Comment: @Psioniax There are always improvements to be made.

Comment: I  close voted it "*This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*"  It is nowhere near the shortest possible program which demonstrates something being inside the loop that mustn't, it's a simple error and it's not likely to help anyone.

Comment: The example is closed now. I guess it wasn't that totally valid.

Comment: "what can I do about it?" you could also improve it by editing if you see a spark of greatness in it. making shinning pearls and that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

George wrote this as a comment for some reason.

## Downvote.

Getting rid of questions like that is more work than it's worth. Getting them ranked lower on search results is easy though: one click, and it's done. Do it. Do it now. And then go do something more interesting, confident in the knowledge that you've done all that is required.

The only exception I'd make for this would be in cases where someone took the time to write a really brilliant "teach a man to fish" answer. In those cases, editing the question to [generalize it for the benefit of others](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) may be worthwhile.

Comment: Downvote costs one point.

Comment: @SQLGeorge Only for answers. Downvoting questions is free.

Comment: Thanks, as I already said in my comment, I did downvote it. Also if you look in my activity tab most of my votes are downvotes. But I asked this question thinking there could be something more to do.

Comment: @approxiblue oh, I didn't know this ! Then happy downvoting. Lately, there is indeed a lot of crap at SO. People just copy-pasting a bunch of code and asking "it doesn't work - please help me". That's not what SO was made for.

Comment: @SQLGeorge it's not as of late. This is an ongoing trend you'll see the longer you're here. Unfortunately users answer these questions to get points

Comment: @SQLGeorge "it doesn't work - please help me" There used to be a "minimal effort" close reason but it was not reinstated because of fear of misuse. Also unconditional downvoting may be prone to misuse.

Comment: @SQLGeorge I just saw the 33 downvotes on the linked example question. This could be seen as a bit irrational "happy" downvoting and might indicate a misuse. Compared to other questions with such a low score the question is indeed not that bad. I would say it is a -4 to +2 question judging by the other questions I see daily on SO.

Answer (score -4):

I'm going to stick my head out here and say **don't downvote**.

He provided too many lines for it to be a good [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but apart from that he provided:

- code to reproduce the behaviour
- his unexpected result
- the result he tries to produce

The question isn't excellent, but but it's good enough that anyone can look at it and immediately understand what's wrong with his code.

Your concern seems to be that his problem is too easy. The question is too stupid.

I imagine this is some 12 year old kid learning PHP. As it stands now his question has 26 downvotes and not a single user left a comment to explain why.

Remember:

> [Down-voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.

Comment: The tooltip for downvotes on questions: _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."_ I would argue that the question does not show research effort, as the point of a _loop_ is to _repeat_ something. It would then stand to reason, and be obvious to most who have actually looked into what a loop _does_, that putting a command in a loop would cause it to repeat each time the loop is called. I would also argue the question is _not useful_ as I would expect the question to help very few people as it sits. (How many others will run into that issue? Likely few.)

Comment: I'm not saying _"don't down-vote any question that is answerable"_. I'm saying _"down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases"_. From the votes I see that users agree with you. Maybe it is considered extreme then not to understand the concept of a loop or a HTML table. I usually down-vote the questions where people just dump code and ask whats wrong. That's what I consider to be in the extreme end.

Comment: "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing." Obviously this was written in another time. The general sentiment has changed. If you read SO meta frequently you see many people in fear about loosing the battle for high quality, even with closing and downvotes and everything else you can imagine. Even more, SO is seen as the worlds largest live debugger. And the only question is where to draw the line if that is still possible.